CORS issue when making requests to Spring Cloud Gateway from frontend
I’m working on a microservice architecture with a Spring Cloud Gateway acting as the API gateway.
When I make requests via Postman and Swagger UI to the gateway on port 8090, everything works fine, and I receive a 200 OK response. However, when I try to make the same request from my frontend (running on port 3000), I’m getting a CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/api/v1/accounts/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I’ve set up the CORS configuration in my downstream services rather than in the API Gateway. Here's the setup I have in one of my downstream services:
package com.example.e_commerce.helper.config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

@Configuration
class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration().apply {
            allowedOrigins = listOf(
                "http://localhost:3000",
                "http://192.168.1.35:3000",
                "http://localhost:8090",
                "http://127.0.0.1:8090",
            )
            allowedMethods = listOf("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
            allowCredentials = true
            allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
        }

        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
        return source
    }
}

package com.example.e_commerce.authservice.config

import com.example.e_commerce.authservice.service.UserService
import com.example.e_commerce.helper.config.CorsConfig
import com.example.e_commerce.helper.config.JwtConfig
import com.example.e_commerce.helper.exceptions.GlobalAccessDeniedHandler
import com.example.e_commerce.helper.exceptions.GlobalAuthenticationEntrypoint
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val globalAccessDeniedHandler: GlobalAccessDeniedHandler,
    private val globalAuthenticationEntrypoint: GlobalAuthenticationEntrypoint,
    private val corsConfig: CorsConfig,
    private val jwtConfig: JwtConfig,
) {

    private val whiteList: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/aggregate/*/v3/api-docs",
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/configuration/**"
    )

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf { csrf -> csrf.disable() }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { requests ->
                requests
                    .requestMatchers(*whiteList).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/deactivate/**").hasAnyRole("Admin")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/accounts/login", "/api/v1/accounts/signup").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/exists/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .exceptionHandling {
                it.accessDeniedHandler(globalAccessDeniedHandler)
                it.authenticationEntryPoint(globalAuthenticationEntrypoint)
            }
            .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2 ->
                oauth2.jwt { jwt ->
                    jwt.decoder(jwtConfig.jwtDecoder())
                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtConfig.jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                }
            }
            .sessionManagement { session ->
                session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
            .cors { cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfig.corsConfigurationSource()) }
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(userService: UserService): AuthenticationManager {
        val daoAuthenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider().apply {
            setUserDetailsService(userService)
            setPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder())
        }

        return ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider)
    }
}

I’m wondering if configuring CORS only in the downstream services is the correct approach, or if it should be handled at the API Gateway instead.
How can I resolve this issue and allow CORS requests from my frontend through the API Gateway?
Additional Info:
Spring Boot version: 3.3.4
API Gateway is running on port 8090
Frontend is running on localhost:3000
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

my guess is indeed you need to allow the cors on the gateway. For sure if the request goes through there first

In SpringBoot 3.3.4 : Had the same problem, Postmans regular GET/POST calls ending with 200 OK Responses but the frontend application OPTIONS calls getting 401 CORS errors. I specifically allowed OPTIONS to be made without authentication in my SecurityFilterChain as follows:
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                                                                                                        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

Note that I didn't had to make this special OPTION permitAll for Spring 3.3.1. Maybe they changed something.
